Lighten fill color for each level of Force Directed Tree Amcharts 5
I'm following a tutorial to lighten the colors of nodes in a Force Directed Tree chart in amCharts 5 based on their level. However, I couldn't find the 'level' property as mentioned in the tutorial. Furthermore, the lighten property is also not found. Is there any alternative property or method to achieve this in amCharts 5, or am I missing something in the documentation?
networkSeries.nodes.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return fill.lighten(target.dataItem.level * 0.25);
});

My Current code:
series.circles.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return fill.lighten(target.dataItem.level * 0.25);
});


test.html:196 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lighten')
at Array. (test.html:196:15)
at p.fold (index.js:1:256476)
at n.get (index.js:1:267893)
at n._afterChanged (index.js:1:121765)
at index.js:1:85748
at Array.forEach ()
at Ae._runDirties (index.js:1:85733)
at Ae._renderFrame (index.js:1:86017)
at Ae._runTicker (index.js:1:86364)
at _ticker._ticker (index.js:1:86789)

My data is in following format:
var data = [
    {
        name: "Node 1",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Node 1.1",
                children: [
                    { name: "Node 1.1.1" },
                    { name: "Node 1.1.2" }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Node 1.2",
                children: [
                    { name: "Node 1.2.1" },
                    { name: "Node 1.2.2" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Node 2",
        children: [
            { name: "Node 2.1" },
            { name: "Node 2.2" }
        ]
    }
];

Picture is attached for your reference, Labels are hidden for confidentiality reasons.


Could you share a very simple diagram creation? So that we can reproduce the error?

In amcharts5, you need to initialize ColorSet object.
import { ColorSet } from "@amcharts/amcharts5";

let colorSet = new ColorSet();
series.circles.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
    let level = target.dataItem.get("level") || 0;
    return colorSet.getIndex(level).lighten(level * 0.25);
});

With scripts imported directly into your HTML, instead of directly importing, you need to initialize like this.
const root = am5.Root.new("element_id");
const colorSet = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {});


Also, the level property is not automatically available by default, so you need to calculate it

function assignLevels(data, level = 0) {
    data.forEach(node => {
        node.level = level;
        if (node.children) {
            assignLevels(node.children, level + 1);
        }
    });
}

assignLevels(yourChartData);


@Obad, I just updated my answer, please check.

It's giving me the below error:
test.html:187 Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function     at assignLevels (test.html:187:10)     at test.html:197:1     at HTMLDocument.t (index.js:1:318591)

@Obad Please provide what the data looks like, this error means that the data is not ana array.

Updated my question with data format, kindly have a look.

@Obad, If the data is array it shouldn't show this error, Are you sure that you passed the data in the assignLevels function as a parameter, for example, assignLevels(data)?
it should work successfully as shown in this link https://runjs.co/s/iaMh4E4zG

tweaking the code a little bit worked for me to get the level:
function assignLevels(data, level = 0) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach(node => {
            node.level = level;
            if (node.children) {
                assignLevels(node.children, level + 1);
            }
        });
    } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
        data.level = level;
        if (data.children) {
            assignLevels(data.children, level + 1);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Invalid data type:", typeof data);
    }
}


After getting the level, now It could not recognize the Lighten function:
let colorSet = new ColorSet();
series.circles.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
let level = target.dataItem.get("level") || 0;
return colorSet.getIndex(level).lighten(level * 0.25);
New error:
test.html:214 Uncaught TypeError: colorSet.getIndex(...).lighten is not a function
at Array. (test.html:214:37) . . .

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
